# javascript onblur function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok i have this code

```
<div name="search" id="searchbox">
    <div id="kk"><img src="Images/glss.png"/><input value="search item here..."    type="text" id="inputbox" onclick="clickclear(this, 'search item here...')"  onblur="clickrecall(this,'search item here...')"/></div><button id="submit" onclick="rr()"/> <!--onkeydown="checkForm(event);"-->
</div>
```

and I have this javascript function for the onclick event.

```
      // searchbox functions ( clear & unclear )
function clickclear(thisfield, defaulttext) {
    if (thisfield.value == defaulttext) {
        thisfield.value = "";
    }
}

function clickrecall(thisfield, defaulttext) {
    if ($q == "0"){

    if (thisfield.value == "") {
        thisfield.value = defaulttext;
    }}
    else
    {

    }
}
```

There is no problem on onclick event, as the text in #inputbox is remove when its clicked.

The problem is the onblur function, the default text on the #inputbox is not recall or not restore in onblur event.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged as jQuery? And in your clickrecall function, where's $q coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just stored the default value in data tag and here is the rest: http://jsfiddle.net/8DFJv/